# Unable to display view using two Parameters in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a "Select Year" Parameter for Year.
If I select from "Select Year", then I want to display results for Selected Year and Previous Year (both) in a CrossTab View on the same Sheet.

Please refer to attached to know more about my query.

*Other way (unwanted): *
I tried to create two Calculated Fields (Dimensions Filters for selecting the Year), then created two different sheets - "Selected Period Value" and "previous Period Value", but I want just one sheet to display it together.

```
//Selected Year
IF YEAR([Year]) = INT([Year Parameter]) THEN
INT([Year Parameter])
END

//Previous Year
IF YEAR([Year]) = INT([Year Parameter])-1 THEN
INT([Year Parameter])-1
END
```

[image]

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Just assuming 46.34% and 46.85% as Profit measure.

Create two calculated fields, one for the year selected from parameter and the other for prior year.

Profit_Current calculated field:
IF YEAR([Year]) = INT([Year Parameter]) THEN Profit 
ELSE 0 END

Profit_Previous calculated field:
IF YEAR([Year]) = INT([Year Parameter])-1 THEN Profit 
ELSE 0 END

Use these two calculated fields in cross tab

Let us know if this works!